# Adding a self-built function to terminal

Tags: bash, shell

I created a function that adds a permanent alias to my system from the terminal because i really hate opening bashrc each time. 
Then at the bashrc file i created a function that calls this program when i use aliadd, but i cant really understand how to add the path of the file so it could run.
the function in bashrc is:

```
aliadd()
{
        sudo ./aliasing $1 $2
}
```

But this only work if im in the same directory as aliasing.
how can i add the path im in each time im trying to call this function?

EDIT:
the solution did help me, though i wanted to share that i ended up using
alias aliadd='sudo ~/aliasing' and so i could make the second parameter as long as i wanted, which was a problem when i used it as a function
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where are the pointers? or C code?

Comment: I've suggested the edit for the tags to be 'bash' and 'shell'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `./aliasing` portion says "use the `aliasing` file thats in the *current directory*.  You can hard code a full path instead.  If its in your home directory, you can use `~/aliasing`. Ideally, you'd have that file in the `bin` subdirectory of your home path.

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv ./aliasing ~/bin/aliasing
```

then your bashrc could have:

```
aliadd()
{
    sudo ~/aliasing $1 $2
}
```